# How to get GLatLngBounds for a city in google maps

Tags: google-maps, zooming, bounds

I have to display a user entered city in a google map. 
I find the city ok with GClientGeocoder.getLatLng(address:String, callback:function) but i also need to set the zoom level so the city fits the map.

I found getBoundsZoomLevel(bounds:GLatLngBounds, viewSize:GSize) but i don't know how to get the bounds:GLatLngBounds for the city. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using:
setCenter(center, zoom?, type?)

Where center is the center point, zoom is your desired zoom level and type is optional.

Comment: Yes but the problem is I don't know the zoom level.